# How do I extract location data from firebase to the maps?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently doing a project on Location Tracking Application. It tracks location of the driver and displays it to the students. So I made Database in Firebase and stored location and basic data of driver to the database. Now i want to retrieve that location co-ordinates to the student interface. I want to create a button in the student activity that contains driver identity so when the student clicks it, it shows the location of driver. How can I do it? Can I do this all in 1 app or do i need to make another app for student? Help me. Thanks[This is driver location data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdEe4.png)

Comment: Okay sorry i didn't know. :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case this my method to get lat&lon then show to Google Map

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // latitude and longitude

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = dataSnapshot.child("Checkin");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> checkinchildren = dataSnapshot1.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot datasnapshotchekinchildren : checkinchildren){
                ChekinModel chekinModel = datasnapshotchekinchildren.getValue(ChekinModel.class);
                Log.e("latitude :", chekinModel.getLatitude());
                /*listlatitude.add(chekinModel.getLatitude());*/
                // create marker
                lat = Double.parseDouble(chekinModel.getLatitude());
                lng = Double.parseDouble(chekinModel.getLongitude());
                 title = chekinModel.getTime();
                uid = chekinModel.getUid();
                nama = chekinModel.getNama();

                latlngs.add(new LatLng(lat,lng));
                for (LatLng points : latlngs){
                    options.position(points);
                    options.title(""+nama+" at : "+title);
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

                    googleMap.addMarker(options);

                }
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(lat, lng)).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                MapsInitializer.initialize(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
                mapView.onResume();









            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```